# How can get correct Column Name from Database with Npgsql?

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, npgsql

This is my table in database:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass),
  hc character varying(30),
  "Hc" character varying(30),
  "HC" character varying(30),
  f character varying(30),
  "F" character varying(30),
  f1 character varying(30),
  te numeric(2,2),
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

If i get a Table Definition by Npgsql from vb.net:

```
select * from test where null = null
```

Result: some colums had changed name:
Ex: Hc => Hc1,HC => HC2
[image]

How can get correct Column Name from Database with Npgsql?

Comment: Can you please post some code showing exactly what you're doing? Getting the field names with `NpgsqlDataReader.GetName()` shows the correct names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you (directly or indirectly) use [`DbDataAdapter.Fill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill) which renames columns as follows if necessary:

> If the DbDataAdapter encounters duplicate columns while populating a
>   DataTable, it generates names for the subsequent columns, using the
>   pattern "columnname1", "columnname2", "columnname3", and so on.

Apparently, this deduplication process treats column names in a case-insensitive way which is why the columns also get renamed in your example. There is no way to turn off this behavior directly (see [AdapterUtil.cs,2402](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/Common/AdapterUtil.cs,2402)).

A work around would be to use an additional `SqlCommand` and use `SqlDataReader.GetName` to obtain the exact column names and then change the columns of the `DataTable` accordingly. This could be done as follows:

```
Dim query = "select * from test where null = null"

' setup connection
Dim connection As New NpgsqlConnection(
    String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Database={2};User Id={3};Password={4};",
                  host, port, database, user, password))
connection.Open()

' fill data table from query
Dim table As New DataTable
Using adapter = New NpgsqlDataAdapter(query, connection)
    adapter.Fill(table)
End Using

' correct column names
Using command = New NpgsqlCommand(query, connection)
    Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
        For i = 0 To table.Columns.Count - 1
            table.Columns(i).ColumnName = reader.GetName(i)
        Next
    End Using
End Using

' display table in DataGridView
view.DataSource = table
```